# Tablesaw.js causing multiple console issues like placeholder is undefined, focus() is not a function

Tags: jquery, responsive, tablelayout

I have been using tablesaw.js for the responsive table layout like swipe and toggle category it was working fine until I use colspan property in the TH and TD,since it's causing multiple js issues likes placeholder is undefined, focus () is not function, as well the hidden columns are visible in the IE11, but working fine in chrome, but still showing console on both browsers.

Version: Tablesaw - v3.1.1
plugins files:
tablesaw.js
tablesaw-init.js

Reference plugin link:
http://filamentgroup.github.io/tablesaw/demo/toggle.html

tablesaw.js version updated from 3.1.0 to 3.1.1 resolved placeholder issues

[image]
[image]